# Implementar Triggers no Postgre

Tags: postgresql, trigger, pl-sql

Tem como implementar uma trigger para funcionar em uma coluna que está presente em todas tabelas do banco de dados?

Comment: Defina "uma coluna presente em todas as tabelas"...

Comment: em todas as tabelas do banco eu tenho uma coluna com data de modificação.

Answer (score 3):

Se as tabelas mencionadas não sofrem operações de `UPDATE`, certemente uma `TRIGGER` **não seria necessária** para resolver o seu problema.

Você pode alterar as colunas de todas as tabelas que contém a data/hora, adicionando um valor `DEFAULT` que seria a data/hora atual do sistema obtido por meio da função `now()`:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ALTER COLUMN coluna SET DEFAULT now();
```

Por Exemplo, o campo `data_acao` da hipotética tabela `historico`:

```
-- TABELA ORIGINAL
CREATE TABLE historico
(
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    id_usuario INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_acao INTEGER NOT NULL,
    data_acao TIMESTAMP
);

-- ALTERANDO TABELA ORIGINAL INCLUINDO O VALOR DEFAULT
ALTER TABLE historico ALTER COLUMN data_acao SET DEFAULT now();

-- REGISTRANDO NO HISTORICO AS ACOES DOS USUARIO
INSERT INTO historico ( id_usuario, id_acao ) VALUES ( 100, 1 );
INSERT INTO historico ( id_usuario, id_acao ) VALUES ( 200, 1 );
INSERT INTO historico ( id_usuario, id_acao ) VALUES ( 300, 1 );
INSERT INTO historico ( id_usuario, id_acao ) VALUES ( 100, 2 );
INSERT INTO historico ( id_usuario, id_acao ) VALUES ( 300, 2 );
INSERT INTO historico ( id_usuario, id_acao ) VALUES ( 100, 3 );
INSERT INTO historico ( id_usuario, id_acao ) VALUES ( 200, 3 );
```

Saída com os registros das `ações` realizadas por `usuários` que foram gravados na tabela `historico`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9af35/1)

Porém, se as tabelas mencionadas sofrem operações de `UPDATE`, seria necessário a criação de uma `TRIGGER` que seria disparada antes da atualização do campo de data/hora (`BEFORE UPDATE`), por exemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION atualizar_data_hora() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
BEGIN 
    NEW.data_acao := now(); 
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Uma vez que com a `TRIGGER FUNCTION` criada, você é capaz de associa-la a quantas tabelas forem necessárias por meio da criação de uma `TRIGGER`, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_nome BEFORE UPDATE ON tabela FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE atualizar_data_hora();
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/abfc3/1)

Comment: Engraçado, no PostgreSQL você cria função e na trigger manda executar procedimento

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado: Exatamente, são 2 objetos diferentes a `TRIGGER FUNCTION` e a `TRIGGER`. A mesma `TRIGGER FUNCTION` pode ser disparada por diferentes `TRIGGERS` em tabelas diferentes. Repare que a "assinatura" de uma `TRIGGER FUNCTION` é sempre a mesma: Não recebe nada como parametro e seu retorno é sempre `RETURNS TRIGGER`.